# Is Fritz 15 a better chess software than Deep Fritz 14?

Tags: software

I can only afford one. Would Fritz 15 be better to get than Deep Fritz 14?

I would like to use Fritz to study opening theory.

Comment: Better in terms of engine strength or what else? Multi-core support? It's important to know because only the "deep" version supports multi-cores. Fritz is most likely a stronger engine than 14.

Comment: Would Fritz 15 be better for studying opening theory than Fritz 14 and analyzing my tournament games? What are multi-cores?

Comment: The deep version should give you better performance because it uses multicore. However, why wouldn't you just buy Deep Fritz 15? Chessbase usually offer a "deep" version for their new product.

Comment: I want to, but I haven't heard of a Deep Fritz 15 coming out. I'm not sure when it's going to come out.

Comment: "Deep" is no longer relevant.  Chessbase says:  "But what about Deep Fritz 15? There is no such thing, because Fritz 15 is already a multiprocessor version! Theoretically, the Fritz 15 engine can use the computing power of up to 2048 cores simultaneously."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I'm not sure what exactly Fritz 15 will offer (because it hasn't been released), but it's almost certain that there will be a "deep" version. Look at this ChessBase online [search](http://shop.chessbase.com/en/search?query=fritz%2014&cat=0), so it's pretty safe to assume there will be Deep Fritz 15. My suggestion: wait for the upcoming version.

However, I don't think Deep Fritz 15 will offer you anything that Deep Fritz 14 doesn't. If we're talking about the user-interface experience, there shouldn't be much because ChessBase always ship an almost-identical software every year.

The most obvious change is the engine, unfortunately, this is not very interesting because Fritz is quite far behind Stockfish and Komodo. If you're looking for the strongest possible engine to study opening theory, you might as well download Stockfish and use it with any compatible client. It's free and plays better chess than Fritz.

You'll need to decide what exactly you want: an easy but expensive bundle from ChessBase or the strongest free chess engine.

**EDIT (after product release)**

It's nice ChessBase finally drops the "deep" term and it makes perfect sense, who is still using 32 bits in 2015? There is no Deep Fritz 15, just Fritz 15.

Comment: Deep never had anything to do with 32-bit vs. 64-bit. It was about how many processors it could use.

Answer (score 3):

There will be no Deep Fritz 15, because Fritz 15 offers Multi-Core.

Answer (score 3):

2017 post update:

I tested both of them and they are almost the same and Identical in engine tests. just less than 10 percent difference in game win rate. I also tested many other engines against fritz which most of the time they win it easily. (engines like: Sugar , Houdini 6, Komodo 11, Stockfish 8, adnsacs). 
I added the bullet games table here. Anyway even with longer time controls fritz loses.
[image]

Comment: Having 10% difference in win rating is fairly big.

Comment: Yes around 200 to 400 ELO difference.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it will be interesting to see, because the Fritz 15 engine is brand new, and written by Vasik Rajlich, the programmer that previously wrote the Rybka chess engine. The London chess shop's webpage for Fritz 15 lists some features, but doesn't speak to anything specific about the engine.

http://shop.chess.co.uk/Fritz-15-64-bit-multiprocessor-version-PC-DVD-p/pre-order-151187.htm

Comment: It's interesting in that sense, but the playing strength won't be close to Stockfish or Komodo.

Comment: How can you know that?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the change in programmer I would think fritz 15 would be stronger than Fritz 14. I can be almost positive without actually testing it that it will be.

To learn opening theory you probably would need an opening database rather than just the chess engine, however to find innovation in the opening and get better move choices then a better chess engine is required.

**What is a core?**

*A multi-core processor is a single computing component with two or more independent actual processing units (called "cores"), which are the units that read and execute program instructions.*

Thus a core is a processing unit (a cpu or just the pu). Multi-core means more work can be done by the computing device simultaneously. This enables Fritz to analyze quicker and therefore deeper.

- Better objective choice would be Fritz 15.
- Better subjective choice would probably be Fritz 14. The reasoning behind this is due to who you are aiming to beat with this opening knowledge. If its not FM/IM/GMs then it hardly matters. Of course the price paid must be less than the cost of Fritz 15.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Deep Fritz 15... it is already multi-cores.

Answer (score 0):

Fritz 16 is now available.  I have Fritz 15 and do not plan on getting 16.  You should buy the version you can afford, but Fritz is a great learning tool, be warned if you're not computer savvy Fritz is a difficult program.